# Install custom php modules with chef solo

Tags: chef, chef-solo

I've tried to search but unfortunately I don't find any documentation or article about how to install custom php modules like pdo_mysql when provisioning with chef solo.

If you do know, I'd be very glad to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the PHP cookbook available here: https://github.com/priestjim/chef-php it contains a lot of extra modules as recipes and supports both rhel & debian platform families. FYI, if you use CentOS, the cookbook depends on https://github.com/priestjim/chef-yumrepo too for the Atomic PHP packages!